Can't access root on my server
I already have two questions sort of going this direction (Can't use sudo anymore since running chmod: sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable) and (Can't use sudo anymore since running chmod: sudo: /etc/sudo.conf is world writable).
I can't access root via ssh anymore because I messed up my system. But my question is, is the server shell automatically root? Would I be able to connect a monitor to my server and use the shell directly on the server to access as root user or would that not change anything?

See How do I boot into a root shell?

FYI, you DO NOT need three separate questions because of the core problem of breaking your system.  Next time, only ask one question, indicating what the core root problem is.  I have closed the other questions as duplicates of this one.

You're better off just doing a clean installation of the system and not writing data to the disks you don't want to.  The "shell" on a server requires login like any other terminal, so it doesn't default to a "root prompt".  If you need to forcibly gain root you need to boot into a root shell which requires shutting down your system anyways.  At that point just boot to installation media and wipe your core Ubuntu drive (it won't touch drives you don't tell it to during install) and then reinstall and you'll have most if not all of those sudo/root issues solved instantly.

Thank you for your reply. I opened three separate questions because, if I didn't misunderstand, I was told to do so You shouldn't ask follow-up questions in comments, instead open a new question with sufficient details, that's the best way to get helpful answers. AskUbuntu is a Q&A site, not a forum. I'm sorry for any inconvenience that caused. I'll be sure not to do that again!
Anyways, thanks for the advice, I will just wipe my core Ubuntu drive and reinstall the system, I'll be careful not to mess anything up. Thanks again!

you could just start all over by installing again and be more careful this time.  but if you have important data on this computer that you want to keep then do NOT re-install. if you can still boot from your install media, try that and choose to just run its own system instead of installing.  this should give you root access.  then you can mount the partition you messed up and fix it as root.  be sure to "umount" it when done or shutdown cleanly.
